# Can I set Intel XDK's emulator to default to landscape orientation?

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I've built an app, and I want to test it in the landscape view. Every time I emulate the code, I have to change the device orientation in the emulator. Is there any way to modify the emulator config so that the default orientation is landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator tab remembers the orientation whenever I switch to it. Is is possible you're using something like setAutoRotate (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493045) or setRotateOrientation (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493051) in your init code (the device ready code)? That might be doing it.

Comment: yes that is it I didn;t notice it because the line was written in the main.js file , but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

That is possible do it the way next:

1. Go the project properties.
2. Build Settings
3. Orientation

You select, landscape or portrait. If you emule the project, you see the changes.